# test ./script.sh doit test dont show true output

Tags: zsh

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

doit() {
    if [[ "$1" = "start" ]]; then
        for loc in $(cat all-doc); do
            if ! screen -list | grep -q My-$loc; then
                screen -dmS My-$loc /home/Server -f /home/$loc.cfg
            fi
        done
    elif [[ "$1" = "stop" ]]; then
        for loc in $(cat all-doc); do
            if screen -list | grep -q My-$loc; then
                pkill -f My-$loc;
            fi
        done
    else
        echo "Option: ERROR..."
    fi
}

nothing() {
    if [[ "$1" = "start" ]]; then
        echo "Option: 1"
    elif [[ "$1" = "stop" ]]; then
        echo "Option: 2"
    else
        echo "Option: 3"
    fi
}

case "$2" in
    start)
           "$1" "$2";
           ;;
    stop)
           "$1" "$2";
           ;;
    restart)
           restart;
           ;;
    *)
           echo "Usage: $0 {doit|nothing} {start|stop|restart}"
           exit 1
           ;;
esac

exit 0
```

> Output:

```
./script.sh:34> case test (start)
./script.sh:34> case test (stop)
./script.sh:34> case test (restart)
./script.sh:34> case test (*)
./script.sh:45> echo 'Usage: ./script.sh {start|stop|restart}'
sage: ./script.sh {start|stop|restart}
./script.sh:46> exit 1
```

this script for start and stop and restart my servers.
If $2 not match with "start" "stop" "restart" in both function must call `else` but not work.
Ok question is why `./script.sh doit test` did not call
`else
        echo "Option: ERROR..."`
whats the sulotion ? Is there better way to do somthing for ./script.sh $1 $2 i mean $1 get function and $2 get start|stop|restart ?

Comment: as you know @Cyeus

Comment: Bit late to the party, but you didn't reach the `echo "Option: ERROR..."` because the `case` didn't call `doit` as the second parameter you passed when calling the script was `test`, so the `case` executed its default statement which is to print the usage and exit. Calling `doit test` from your script would have printed the `Option: ERROR...` message, but the `case` will never make that call since it only calls a variable function when its second param is either start or stop